# What is the trick in this website?

Tags: python, urllib

I can access this webpage in my firefox browser:
http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/74.82.190.99
So I can get the information about this IP.

However, when I fetch it using Python, there will be errors:

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/74.82.190.99")
print f.read()
```

I get this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /ip_tracer/74.82.190.99
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

I take a look into the page's source code:

```
<form action="/ip_tracer/" method="post">
<div>
<input id="ipqry" name="QRY" type="text" value="74.82.190.99" size="18" maxlength="255" onclick="cleanup(this)">
<input type="submit" value="Track IP, host or website" onclick="progress(true)">
</div>
</form>
```

And I use the `POST` method, the result is the same:

```
import urllib 
params = urllib.urlencode({'QRY': '74.82.190.99'}) 
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/", params) 
print f.read()
```

The result is the same `403 Forbidden`.

Can anyone give me a hint? I am using Python 2.5 on Windows XP.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably the server reads your [`User-Agent`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) header and decides not to serve your request. Alternatively it can rely on some other headers being typically set by normal browsers (like FF).

I tried this one:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request("http://www.ip-adress.com/ip_tracer/74.82.190.99")
request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; es-ES; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5")

f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print f.read()
```

and got the proper result.

NOTE: Please check the Terms of Service of the site if you plan to use it programmatically. It might violate their rules if you keep sending such requests automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the User-Agent knowledge. And thanks for the heads-up. I wont harass that website. Even I do, I will use proxies. :)

Answer (score 0):

It probably read the origin of the `POST` command and sees that it doesn't come from a valid host and denies you.

Comment: You mean `HTTP referrer`? It seems not. Because I put the address directly into the firefox, it also works. It doesnt even need `POST` method.

Comment: Yes that was what I meant, some scripts does some checking if the formdata is coming from the same server the script itself resides on. But not in this case it seems! :)